# Specifying Array list size and capacity?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have created an arraylist like this

```
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);

i.add(1);
i.add(2);
i.add(3);
i.add(4);
```

But I am not getting any exception though i have defined initial capacity as 2 why is not throwing any exception?
Does the List grows automatically after it reaches the mentioned capacity??

Comment: Because that's what ArrayLists are - they are flexible and can shrink or expand when needed unlike arrays which have fixed size...

Comment: Strong suggestion: Read the description at the top of the JavaDoc for `ArrayList`.

Comment: Copied literally from the javadoc: "As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically."

Answer (score 3):

The initial capacity isn't a limit. It represents how much data can be put into the list before the list has to be reallocated.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting an exception because you make **assumptions** on behavior ... which you didn't bother to cross-check. When code doesn't behave as you expect, far too often your expectations are wrong.

And in such cases, you turn to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and find:

*Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically.*

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is spot-on correct, and sage advice to any novice programmer.